# In a safe finite field elliptic curve, why is p not n?

Tags: elliptic-curves, domain-parameters

From what I understand, in order for a curve to be safe, it would appear that $n$ being the order of the cyclic subgroup of the curve, is a prime. Also, it is the theoretical upper-bound on the number of private keys the curve can issue, thus it should be a good candidate for being the limit on the size of the field.

However in practice, it looks like we always choose a different $p$ than $n$. Why do we do this? Also, I'd understand that if $p$ is smaller than $n$, but why do we sometimes have a larger $p$ than $n$? It won't be possible to have up to $p$ private keys when the subgroup has order $n$ right? Lastly, I see some tutorials referring to $p$ as the characteristic of the curve, what does that mean?

I'd love to understand the above a bit further, and I guess in general my question is, given $n$, how would I choose $p$ for a safe curve?

Comment: A curve whose order equals the cardinality of the base field is called *anomalous*. Look into it.

Comment: Thank you for the note. I tried to looking online but couldn't locate information on the properties of anomalous elliptic curves. Would you mind help pointing me to some resources? Thank you.

Comment: If you search for "anomalous curve" as suggested, you should find papers / thesises on polynomial-time attacks on the ECDLP for these curves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also, I'd understand that if p is smaller than n, but why sometimes we have a larger p than n? It won't be possible to have up to p private keys when the subgroup has order n right?

I suspect you're using an analogy with more normal discrete log problem, where the value is a value between 0 and $p-1$; obviously, you can't have more than $p$ values.

In contrast, the standard way of viewing an elliptic curve point is that is a solution $(x, y)$ to an equation such as $y^2 \equiv x^3 + ax + b \pmod p$ for fixed values $a, b, p$ (or a special "point at infinity", an artificial group member that's needed to make the group closed).

As a point consists of two values, each of which are between 0 and $p-1$, we have $p^2+1$ values that are potential candidates to be group members.  It should be obvious that the vast majority of those potential solutions aren't actually solutions to the equation; it turns that that there will always be approximately $p$ solutions (within the "Hasse interval"); and this "approximately" can be slightly larger or slightly smaller than $p$ (but always within $\sqrt{2p}$)

> given n, how would I choose p for a safe curve?

At your level of understanding, you don't.  The issues in selecting a curve are subtle, and you currently don't know nearly enough.  Instead, you should rely on someone who does know what they are doing to choose a good curve (which specifies $p$ and $n$) for you.

> Lastly, I see some tutorials referring to p as the characteristic of the curve, what does that mean?

Elliptic curves are defined using an equation over a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)); for cryptography, we always use a finite field (as we generally prefer our ciphertexts to be expressible in a bounded number of bits).  A finite field always has exactly $p^k$ elements, where $p$ can be any prime, and $k$ any positive integer. We define the characteric as the value $c$ where we always have $\underbrace{x+x\ +...+\ x}_{c\text{ times}} = 0$ for all field elements $x$ (and where addition is the field addition operation).  It turns out that, for all finite field, we have $c=p$ (even if $k>1$).

Currently, it is most common to have elliptic curves with $p$ being a large prime and $k=1$; in this case, you can perform the field addition and multiplication operations modulo $p$ (for $k>1$, it gets more complicated), and the modulus $p$ is the characteristic.

Comment: WRT to domain parameter generation: there are of course libraries that implement domain parameter generation for you, so creating your own set would then be analogous to pressing a button. This is especially true for DH. For ECC it is also possible, but I'd get some coffee before starting the calculations; using a **named curve** would be highly recommended instead.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes It would be much more efficient to get coffee *while* running the calculations

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. I have a follow up question, the part that confuses me heavily is, you mentioned that c = p where cx = 0. My understanding was that the subgroup order of the curve in finite field, n, has such a property where nx = 0. As I understand now, n is the order of the subgroup, but p is the characteristic of the subgroup, it now appears that they are equivalent? Yet in many curves they aren't the same, sorry for asking really primitive questions and I've missed in my understanding by a huge mile. Thanks!

Comment: 'c=p where cx=0'; actually, I wrote $\underbrace{x+x\ +...+\ x}_{c\text{ times}} = 0$; that is not multiplication (at least, not the field multiplication operation).  If multiplication within $cx$ is the field operation, then the only solutions for $cx=0$ are $c=0$ or $x=0$.

Comment: 'p is the characteristic of the subgroup'; actually, it's the characteristic of the field that the curve is defined on.  It has nothing to do with any subgroups that might be in the elliptic curve group.

Comment: Wait, really? Assuming x is a generator field element in a cyclic subgroup of the finite elliptic curve field, isn't the order defined to be the number in which under field multiplication with the generator to be 0? When I say subgroup, I mean the subgroup chosen in a curve to be used for the purpose of field operations under encryption schemes. I would love additional insight on directionally where I failed, thanks!

Comment: 'isn't the order defined to be...'; actually, we're defining the characteristic of the field, not the order of any element of the field.  As for 'the subgroup chosen in a curve to be used for field operations', that really doesn't make much sense.  We sometimes use a subgroup of the elliptic curve group elements to do crypto with, but that doesn't have much to do with the field that we use to define the curve with.

Comment: Yep I totally agree that the subgroup we choose for crypto purpose and order of an element in the field doesn't have to do with how we define a curve. Apologies as I've probably not been clear enough. My question was mostly centric around, given a defined curve, as we choose a subgroup based on a generator element, what is the relationship between the produced $p$ and $n$ parameter of the elliptic group for crypto purpose.

Comment: @gtr32x: if we define a subgroup of a curve, the size of that subgroup will always be a factor of $n$; we (almost) always pick a curve where $n = hq$, where $h$ is a small integer (the "cofactor"), and $q$ is a large prime; we work in a subgroup of size $q$.  $p$ really isn't involved in this...

Comment: Which now circles back to my question in the beginning...why don't we just use $n$ for $p$? And in general, how is $p$ even chosen?

Comment: @gtr32x: if your question is "why don't we pick a curve with $n=p$?"; well, we could, but (as mentioned in the comments) it turns out that those curves are extremely weak.  As for how $p$ is chosen, well, any prime of the appropriate size would work; what's typically done is pick a large prime $p$ that makes the modulo operation cheap (e.g. $p=2^{255}-19$).

Comment: Thank you so much poncho! I really appreciate the patience with getting thru this with me!

Comment: @poncho are ec operations mod the subgroup order or the field order in curve25519?

Comment: @Woodstock: for computing an operation on the point themselves (e.g. point addition), you do it in the field (that is, mod the field characteristic for prime curves such as curve25519).  For higher level operations on the multiplier (e.g. in EdDSA), you can compute those mod the subgroup order.